# Convert string to path to use it with Unzip in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, path, google-colaboratory

I'm working with a Jupyter notebook in Google Colaboratory and I want to unzip file that it is on my Google Drive into /tmp folder.

I have tried this:

```
import os

root_dir = '/tmp/omniglot/data/'
!unzip '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/omniglot.zip' -d path.path(root_dir)
```

But I get the error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

I have also tried:

```
from pathlib import Path

root_dir = '/tmp/omniglot/data/'
!unzip '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/omniglot.zip' -d Path(str_path)
```

But I get the same error.

How can I use the string `root_dir` with unzip?

My Python version is 3.6.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{varname}` syntax to pass Python variables into the shell.

```py
import os

root_dir = '/tmp/omniglot/data/'
os.makedirs(root_dir, exist_ok=True)  # Create a target directory if doesn't exist

!unzip '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/omniglot.zip' -d {root_dir}
```

You can also use zipfile from standard library.

```py
import zipfile

root_dir = '/tmp/omniglot/data/'
zip_file = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/omniglot.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(root_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it (without using `!unzip` command):

```
import os
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path

# Create destination folder if it doesn't exist.
Path(root_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

local_zip = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/omniglot.zip'

zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip, 'r')

zip_ref.extractall(root_dir)
zip_ref.close()
```